# Unpacking list of tuples as numpy array for Experience replay

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am implementing DDPG, for that purpose I am storing the experience as a tuple in a deque. When I sample experience from the deque, it is basically a list of tuple which I am unpacking using the following code.

```
experiences = self.replay_buffer.sample(self.batch_size)
states, next_states=zip(*[[experience[0], experience[3]] for experience in experiences])
states=np.asarray(states)
next_states = np.asarray(next_states)
```

My question is that is there an elegant way to extract states and next_states. I have tried with np.hsplit but that doesn't work 
Edit: For reference, my list of tuples look like following

```
[(array([-0.93204219,  0.36234977,  0.71115057]), array([-0.10888829]), -7.727945120405118, array([-0.9484591 ,  0.31689957,  0.96657966])), (array([-0.61368157,  0.78955362, -0.89166572]), array([-0.85101601]), -5.059874000549156, array([-0.59667989,  0.80247935, -0.4271529 ])), (array([-0.98349325, -0.18094481,  8.        ]), array([0.18540606]), -15.159536549872858, array([-0.83834718, -0.54513669,  7.8921023 ]))]
```

The first element of each tuple is a state, second is the action, third is the reward, and last is the next_state and the format of states i want is like following

```
array([[-0.93204219,  0.36234977,  0.71115057],
       [-0.61368157,  0.78955362, -0.89166572],
       [-0.98349325, -0.18094481,  8.        ]])
```

Comment: What type / format is `experiences`? A 2D array?

Comment: The inner dimension is 4. [state, action, reward, next_state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that should work. Whether it's elegant I don't know.

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sns = np.empty((2, len(experiences), 3))
>>> states, next_states = sns
>>> any(map(sns.transpose(1,0,2).__setitem__, count(), map(itemgetter(0, 3), experiences)))
False
# states and next_states should now contain the result
```

But

```
>>> states = np.array([e[0] for e in experiences])
>>> next_states = np.array([e[3] for e in experiences])
```

is faster and simpler.

Comment: Thanks, but the output that comes from this is basically a numpy array of numpy arrays which is not acceptable by the keras model. I can achieve the same results through np.asarray(experiences)[:, 0].

Comment: @hakaishinbeerus Hm, I guess it would help if you could show in your question what your data look like. The thing I wrote I tested on a list of tuples of floats where it works just fine.

Comment: I have added more details

Comment: @hakaishinbeerus Thanks. It seems that the boring straight-forward method (see bottom of my post) is actually the best I can find. I'll delete this in a day or two, I don't think it is very illuminating.

Comment: np.asarray works for me. I knew this method all long, just didn't find it aesthetic enough to use.

Comment: Turns out I cannot delete an accepted answer. So the world will have to live with it.